# OFX4J parse exception after it was working just fine - aggregate SONRS

Tags: java, ofx

I had a piece of code to read ofx file to retrieve several tags (such as acct number, balance etc.) I am using net.sf.ofx4j

Piece of code:

```
public void parse(String filename) throws OFXParseException, IOException, SQLException {

        AggregateUnmarshaller<ResponseEnvelope> unmarshaller = new AggregateUnmarshaller<ResponseEnvelope>(
                ResponseEnvelope.class);
        FileInputStream file = null;

        try {
            file = new FileInputStream(filename);
            ResponseEnvelope envelope = unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

            BankingResponseMessageSet messageSet = (BankingResponseMessageSet) envelope.getMessageSet(MessageSetType.banking);

            List<BankStatementResponseTransaction> responses = messageSet.getStatementResponses();
            for (BankStatementResponseTransaction response : responses) {

                BankStatementResponse message = response.getMessage();
                String currencyCode = message.getCurrencyCode();
                String acct_number = message.getAccount().getAccountNumber();
                double av = message.getAvailableBalance().getAmount();
                double cur = message.getLedgerBalance().getAmount();
                AccountType acct_type = message.getAccount().getAccountType();

            }

        } catch (OFXParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;

    }
```

It was working fine until one day it started throwing the following exception:

net.sf.ofx4j.io.AggregateStackContentHandler onElement
INFO: Element INTU.BID is not supported on aggregate SONRS (class net.sf.ofx4j.domain.data.signon.SignonResponse) at index 70.

net.sf.ofx4j.io.AggregateStackContentHandler onElement
INFO: Element INTU.USERID is not supported on aggregate SONRS (class net.sf.ofx4j.domain.data.signon.SignonResponse) at index 70.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.IOException: Unexpected EOF

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope ofx file format should be changed. because you are requesting (**MessageSetType**.**banking**). But in your ofx file may be have credit card details.

In early,  transaction data is include in .ofx file inside the <**BANKMSGSRSV1**> tag.
But now transaction data is include in <**CREDITCARDMSGSRSV**> tag. you need to change the data receiving code.

Hope you can get some help from this. Thank you